# Calculating a percentage from the res value after deducting itself

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a main variable number. There are static values deducted from it and a 5% value of the result of itself.

Arbitrary values:

```
> 40,000 (start)
- 2,000 (static)
- 300 (static)
- 200 (static)
- 1,785.71429 (5% of 35,714.2857) //Where the bender lies
= 35,714.2857
```

I want to calculate the Value of 1,785.71429

So if one was to change the value of `40,000` to `45,000` then it would look like this:

```
> 45,000 (start)
- 2,000 (static)
- 300 (static)
- 200 (static)
- 2,023.80953 (5% of 40,476.1905) <---
= 40,476.1905
```

Is there a formula that would calculate this for me?

**Edit**

I noticed a problem in my question and fixed it. This is how I reverse calculate it:

```
Cell A2:
=A1+B1+200+300+2000
Cell B1:
=A1*0,05
```

I increment `A1` until the formula above in `A2` gives me the `start` number for example `45,000`

[image]

Comment: What you are trying to calculate I'm unable to solve it  !! Could you write what formula you have used to get those values?

Comment: @RajeshS I see that what I posted was wrong, I am fixing it then giving you the formula how I got it

Comment: @RajeshS I have added all the information I can give you

Comment: I need to work it out without running into the `Circular Reference` error

Comment: *I want to calculate the Value of 1,785.71429* It is (40000 - 2000 - 300 - 200) * (5%) / (100% + 5%).

Comment: WOW, Thank you @Akina I do not understand what you just did there, It breaks my brain. Please post an elaborated answer, I'll mark it correct

Comment: I got it to work by enabling `Iterative Calculation` in `Excel Options > Formulas > Calculation options`. But your calculation works better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to calculate the Value of 1,785.71429

Let's think.

We have 40000$ and spend 2000$, 300$ and 200$.

The reminder is 40000 - 2000 - 300 - 200 = 37500$.

We need to divide it for 2 parts. First of it is 5% of second one. So second is 100%, and their sum is 100% + 5% = 105%. And it is 37500$.

To calculate 1% we must divide: 37500/105=357.14

To calculate 5% we must multiply: 357.14*5=1785.7

That's all.

Comment: But if it is `1%` you want to calculate, shouldn't the `1%` formula be `37500/101=371.28`? or what if the remainder value is `8%` of the NET value?

Comment: If you need 1% instead of 5%, you must divide by 101 (and multiply by 1), that's right. If 8%, you must divide by 108 and multiply by 8 obtaining 2777.78... and so on...